# SQLite delete rows from table that are NOT selected

Tags: sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and have selected the specific rows I need from the database (aka the rows that are missing values). Can anyone help me develop a query that would delete all of the rows that were NOT selected? Here's what I have so far for selecting:

```
SELECT * FROM BadData_Table   
WHERE A IS NULL OR A = ''
    OR B IS NULL OR B = ''
    OR C IS NULL OR C = ''
    OR D IS NULL OR D = ''
    OR E IS NULL OR E = ''
    OR F IS NULL OR F = ''
    OR G IS NULL OR G = ''
    OR H IS NULL OR H = ''
    OR I IS NULL OR I = ''
    OR J IS NULL OR J = '';
```

Comment: Look into the NOT operator for sqlite.  In general if you have a "SELECT WHERE blah" statement you can use "SELECT WHERE NOT blah" to get the opposite rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the operator NOT to the condition as a whole:

```
DELETE FROM BadData_Table   
WHERE NOT (
       A IS NULL OR A = ''
    OR B IS NULL OR B = ''
    OR C IS NULL OR C = ''
    OR D IS NULL OR D = ''
    OR E IS NULL OR E = ''
    OR F IS NULL OR F = ''
    OR G IS NULL OR G = ''
    OR H IS NULL OR H = ''
    OR I IS NULL OR I = ''
    OR J IS NULL OR J = ''
);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
DELETE FROM BadData_Table   
WHERE 
        A IS NOT NULL AND A <> ''
    AND B IS NOT NULL AND B <> ''
    AND C IS NOT NULL AND C <> ''
    AND D IS NOT NULL AND D <> ''
    AND E IS NOT NULL AND E <> ''
    AND F IS NOT NULL AND F <> ''
    AND G IS NOT NULL AND G <> ''
    AND H IS NOT NULL AND H <> ''
    AND I IS NOT NULL AND I <> ''
    AND J IS NOT NULL AND J <> ''
;
```